# How to add jar file to maven

Tags: java

I add a custom jar file to maven project and another one is produce jar file from spring- boot
But when I run pom.xml it is success
But when I run a project in server it gives class not found exception
Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: Can you include more details, such as the full exception and your pom.xml structure?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mvn deploy` in order to deploy the artifact to a remote repository.

> The deploy plugin is primarily used during the deploy phase, to add your artifact(s) to a remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects. This is usually done in an integration or release environment. It can also be used to deploy a particular artifact (e.g. a third party jar like Sun's non redistributable reference implementations).

Read more about `mvn deploy` [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/).

As a result - The code that builds your artifact will be a able to pack the missing jar just as the other jars are packaged.

Comment: In maven project I have to add jar file for accessing the files
The accessing files jar name is utils.jar and I am adding a jar for that file as a local jar dependency 
In new project name is filejar

Dependency in pom.xml
<system as scope>
<path of jar file as systemPath>

 But when I run in putty the jar file didn't find it shows like classnotfoundexception
The dependency is not found in server
I am running like this
Java -jar -DAPP_ROOT_DIR=/home/username/Project name  target/filejar.jar
 Can anyone please help me